# Parameter substitution within rosparam list inside launch file

Tags: rosparam

I am trying to change the parameter `map_frame` within the rosparam list as shown below, but the substitution does not work.

I am actually passing the `"tf_pre"` argument from another launch file.

This line `<rosparam param="map_frame" subst_value="True">$(arg tf_pre)/map </rosparam> # prefix the tf name for the map` is used to pass the value of `tf_pre` to the value of `map_frame` inside the `<rosparam>` list.

This does not seem to have any effect because when I run `rosparam get /h1/slam_gmapping/map_frame` I get the wrong value.

Anyone has an idea what could be wrong?

This runs in ROS Noetic and I am trying to slam a multi robot Gazebo simulation.

```
 <launch>
    
      <arg name="tf_pre" default="robot1" />
    
      <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping">
    
        <rosparam param="map_frame" subst_value="True">$(arg tf_pre)/map </rosparam> # prefix the tf name for the map
    
        <rosparam>
          odom_frame: odom
          base_frame: base_link
          map_frame: map
          ...
    
        </rosparam>
    
      </node>
    </launch>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include an answerable question. You have made a statement only. Also please include enough information to reproduce your environment and share both what you're expecting as well as the result that you're seeing and what's different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided a fully reproducible example to show what is actually going wrong. But based on your description it looks like you're setting that parameter twice and the one that you're trying to parameterize is lower in precedence.

The last instance of the parameter is the one used. http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML#Evaluation_order

Comment: yeah that solved it. 
I moved the <rosparam param="map_frame" subst_value="True">$(arg tf_pre)/map </rosparam> # prefix the tf name for the map
below the parameters list and just before I close the node tag and it worked